# Set IIS to Require SSL + Require Client Certificate on requests from localhost?

Tags: c#, authentication, iis, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

So,

This is my scenario:

1. I have a web service which is invoked by the cruel and mean outside world, and it is hosted in IIS to REQUIRE both SSL and client certificate.
   I.e. no certificate --> no soup for you.
2. Unfortunetaly, this web service should also be invoked by other services running on the same machine, so that a url in form of "http://localhost//someService.." is applied.

I really want to know if there is any way this kind of setup is possible?

I think not, but if anyone knows otherwise, this would be a huge help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would those "local" clients experience if they used the "public" hostname of the service using https (why would it matter)?

Comment: This requires maintenance of client certificates on the local machine which I want to avoid, plus, I think there is a latency penalty if I do the request to the actual public host

Comment: Is your solution designed in a way that the local services could refer the webservice's "meat and potatoes" and not call it as web service but just standard project reference ?

Comment: nope, must send a request.

Comment: What kind of project is this web service ? Do you own the source code for it ? I have an ASP Web API that forces (or not) HTTPs depending on some conditions.

Comment: It's a WCF service, invoked by SOAP messages.

Comment: I own the source code, but for this given case, cannot modify it, looking for a work around to accomplish what I described in the question

Comment: You could have two IIS Website, one requiring SSL/client certificate and the other, not. Make you to attribute a local IP to the one you would not want exposed to your DMZ/WAN.

Comment: First, thanks for your responses. Second,
This requires maintaining two applications on IIS, which I want to avoid. Do you know \ think of a way this can be accomplished while using the same virtual directory?

Comment: Interesting, do/have you tinkered with port forwarding? It's been some time for me and if/when I did something like this it would be with an appliance, so barring that, perhaps in Windows firewall (assuming you can get to it)?

Comment: Can't say I've tried, or even thought of doing it... Is this possible? Do you have a reference to some blog which shows such implementation?

Comment: Its one of those Gandalf moments (almost a decade ago when it comes to tinkering with app firewall/routing and such) for me :)...so instead of wasting your time, try asking on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com)?

Comment: I will leave the post here open and post the question there as well, thanks for your assistance